# Small Arduino with Bluetooth HID interface

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to create a bluetooth gamepad for my phone.

I saw this:

[https://www.amazon.com/DFRobot-Beetle-BLE-Arduino-Bluetooth/dp/B014KQHEH6/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014KQHEH6)

It says its bluetooth HID, but there are some conflicting comments saying it is serial over bluetooth. Is there something similar in a small form factor with an hid bluetooth module that I can use?

Comment: schematic ... https://github.com/Arduinolibrary/DFRobot_Bluno_Bettle/blob/master/DFR0339-Bluno%20beetle%20V1.0.pdf?raw=true .......... uses the cc2540 .... http://www.ti.com/product/cc2540   .... that might tell you what it actually is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that the controller you mentioned has a [TI CC2540 Bluetooth processor](http://www.ti.com/product/CC2540), I have found a few webpages with information about HID capabilities in the CC2540. Based this the CC2540 should support HID.

[Some example code.](https://github.com/rampadc/cc254x-hidKbdM)
[Question on the TI forums, with a link to example code.](http://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/bluetooth_low_energy/f/538/p/120371/430649)